# How can I change namespace prefix in this WSDL?

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, namespaces, prefix

I am trying to create a WSDL for a pre-existing web service. I have an existing client and and existing server, and I've captured the format both use using Wireshark. I am trying to write a new client that uses the same format. Therefore I am trying to match the format as closely as possible, be it correct or not. I'm cooking up a WSDL file using XmlSPY, which I hope then to take to C# and generate interface code.

Here is my WSDL so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.ecerami.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ecerami.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl" name="HelloService">
 <message name="api:create"/>
 <message name="oanda:create">
  <part name="parameter"/>
  <part name="parameter"/>
 </message>
 <portType name="Oanda_PortType">
  <operation name="create">
   <input message="tns:oanda:create"/>
   <output message="tns:api:create"/>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name="Oanda_binding" type="tns:Oanda_PortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="create">
   <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use="encoded"  namespace="oanda.fxtrade.api"/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="oanda.fxtrade.api"/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name="Oanda_service">
  <documentation>WSDL File for Oanda FX Trade API (local SOAP server)</documentation>
  <port name="Oanda_port" binding="tns:Oanda_binding">
   <soap:address location="http://10.0.0.3:18081"/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

Here is a sample message I'm trying to copy. This is what the original client emits:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <oanda:create xmlns:oanda="oanda.fxtrade.api">
      <parameter>FXGAME</parameter>
      <parameter></parameter>
    </oanda:create>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is what XmlSPY says my WSDL will emit for the same message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <m:create xmlns:m="oanda.fxtrade.api">
       <parameter/>
       <parameter/>
      </m:create>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My question for now is - how do I match the "oanda:" prefix generated by the original client? Is this what is called a namespace prefix? Where is the "m:" in my generated code coming from? I can find mentions of this in other examples on this site, but none using WSDL, at least as far as I can tell.

Thank you for any help you can give.

---

When I try to run the above WSDL through svcutil.exe, I get two problems.

1) the XML is not well-formed since you can't have more than one parameter with the same name. XMLSpy was also complaining about this, so I punted on it for now by renaming them to Parameter1 and Parameter2.

The specific error is: "More than one message part named 'parameter' was specified. Each message part must have a unique name."

2) Once past this, I get this error:

"Namespace prefix 'tns:oanda' is not defined."

So, again: How do I change/add a namespace definition in a WSDL file?

Answer (score 4):

The namespace prefix does not matter. The two examples are identical by the rules of XML.

Comment: That may be true, but I'd still like to change the namespace prefix. Surely there is a way to control it, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Namespace prefixes are exactly like variable names. You can alias the namespace with whatever you wish to.

This is analogous to the following java code:

In the first XML: api.fxtrade.onada onada;
In the second XML: api.fxtrade.onada m;

In other words, the 1st XML can be read as:
*referring to the "`oanda.fxtrade.api`" namespace with variable `onada`, the `create` tag in the `onada` namespace,  will have a parameter of value FXGAME*.
The second XML can be read as:
*referring to the "`oanda.fxtrade.api`" namespace with variable `m`, the `create` tag in the `m` namespace,  will have a parameter...*